# get width using width( ) on generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery method `.width()` was used to get the width of the generated element as:

```
html: 
<div class='row-fluid' id='photo-preview'></div>
javascript:
 for(i = 0;i < 4;i++){
    var imageSpan = "<div class='span3' id='span_" + i + "'><img src='" + images[i] +"'></div>"
    $('#photo-preview').append(imageSpan);
    var w = $('#span_' + i).width(); 
    console.log(w);
  }
```

But it got the incorrect value of width. It was the value of percentage instead of pixel. E.g, `w` should be 400 (400px) but the js got 80 (80%).

I thought the problem may be because the element was dynamically generated. In the console I can got the right value with `.width()` when all the elements were loaded.

Any ideas to work around with it?

Comment: try `$(imageSpan).width()` after appending the content

Comment: @Eru thx but it doesn't work

Comment: `.width()` always gives the width in pixels. Are you sure the element's width is not set to 80 pixels? Any chance of seeing a demo?

Comment: can you post the css code?

Comment: if span's width is based on the width of image inside it, you might want to set the width to the span in css, otherwise you have to wait for the image to be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You have to wait for the load event of the image before you can get the correct height.

```
var img = '<img src="img_path.jpg">';
$(img)
    .load(function() {
        console.log("width", $(this).width());
    })
    .appendTo('#photo-preview');
```

Edit: To match with your example :

```
html: 
<div class='row-fluid' id='photo-preview'></div>
javascript:
 for(i = 0;i < 4;i++){
    var img = "<img src='" + images[i] +"'>";
    $(img)
        .load(function() {
            console.log("width", $(this).width());
        })
        .appendTo("<div class='row-fluid' id='photo-preview'>")
        .appendTo('#photo-preview');

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetWidth)

I.E.

```
var w =  $('#span_' + i).offsetWidth;
console.log(w);
```

Here's a really silly fiddle I made. I set the width to 80%. If you go to the console, you should see the pixel width (448 px)

http://jsfiddle.net/bwm5s/